# Responsiven't Jumbotron background image

Tags: bootstrap-4

Setting background-image to jumbotron component ain't functioning responsively, rather it stretches along height and width at times.

Have tried with overriding the jumbotron class setting background-image, background-size to cover. Even tried with height and width adjustments to 100% and auto.

How to get the image to be responsive!

```
.jumbotron.jumbotron-fluid
  .container
    h1.display-4 Fluid jumbotron
    p.lead
      | This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.
```

```css
.jumbotron{
    background: url("https://preview.redd.it/ue9911r3a4ez.jpg?overlay-align=bottom,left&overlay-pad=8,16&crop=636:279,smart&overlay-height=0.10&overlay=%2Fv9vyirk6hl221.png%3Fs%3Db466421949eb723078743745ce6421609d7a9c66&width=636&height=279&auto=webp&s=b1793a09afb650d8f3d2fb2596c40ca1a8240a2e") no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url('...');
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Try using these commands, the image will be responsive but the image may/maynot occupy the whole jumbotron

refer this link(point 4): https://blog.creative-tim.com/web-design/bootstrap-background-image/

Comment: Tried with that. It ain't showing any free space in jumpotron. But there's this issue with resizing. You could check the pen at https://codepen.io/jezwn/pen/RXKqzv. If you slightly change the window size you could see it's responsive at some points.

Comment: use "background-size: contain"  to make it responsive